# Ca't remove options of a selectbox in a form

Tags: javascript, html

I just started to learn javascript and have encountered a small problem.

What I want to achieve is that I could use a radio box to update a select box. The first thing I should be able to do is to remove all the options in the select box. I use the following code:

```
var drop = document.getElementById("selectbox1");
var i;
for(i=drop.options.length-1;i>=0;i--)
{
    drop.remove(i);
}
```

The code above works fine and remove all the options in the select box. However, if I include the select box in a form, it won't work any more. I can see that the page got refreshed but the options were not removed. More specifically, if the HTML is something like below, the above code can not remove the options.

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
   <select id="selectbox1">
     .             //All the options in the select box
     .
     .
   </select>
</form>
```

Can someone help explain what was going wrong?

Comment: I can't reproduce that.

Comment: You could just use a while loop `while(drop.options.length > 0){ drop.remove(0); }` It should not make a difference if it is in a form or not. Is there any JS Errors?

Comment: Check, if you don't have other elements with `id="selectbox1"` in the second case.

Comment: `I can see that the page got refreshed` How do you run your code, on button click? Is it submitting a form?

Answer (score 0):

Without being able to reproduce the error, it's hard to understand exactly what you say is happening. Perhaps it is an issue with you looping over the options? Trying clearing the options like so:

```
document.getElementById("selectbox1").options.length = 0;
```